# Can I add e.g. aliases only once for multiple containers with ddev?

Tags: bash, alias, ddev

I have several projects where I use ddev. I want to configure bash-scripts and aliases like

```
alias ll="ls -lh"
```

for all projects. How can I do this?

My ddev Version is 1.14.2 and I am on a MAC with Bash 5.0.11 configured on my terminal.

I know if I use `.ddev/homeadditions/.bash_aliases` I have all aliases, which I configure in `.bash_aliases`, but I don't want to configure it again and again for each project.

Comment: As you know, you can do this with homeadditions per project, and you can also do it with a post-start hook as the example in https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extending-commands/#exec-execute-a-shell-command-in-a-container-defaults-to-web-container shows. But there's not yet  a way to do it globally.  As you already found out, this is slated for development in https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/2055 in a coming release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DRUD did it. In Version 1.15 you can now add eg. global aliases or whatever you like, that matches .bash_profile .profile or other dotfiles in the home directory.

You just have to move or copy the file:

`~/.ddev/homeadditions/bash_aliases.example` to `~/.ddev/homeadditions/.bash_aliases`

and add your aliasses there.

Now, if your container already runs, use `ddev restart` to "copy" the global aliasfile to the specific container.

If you need functions you can use that file too, like:

```
function test() {
    clear
    echo "Some text"
    ls -lha
}
```

Thanks to @rfay